# SQL left join select first table once

Tags: mysql, sql

Ive currently have the following problem:

I've got a MySQL Query:

```
SELECT account.id as id, `cname`, `username`, `state`, `dow` 
FROM account 
LEFT JOIN zeitplanung 
ON account.id = zeitplanung.user_id 
WHERE account.hide = 0 
and ifnull(zeitplanung.kw,43) = 43 
and ifnull(zeitplanung.year, 2017) = 2017;
```

It returns the usernames and mentioned values for them, in case i've selected the right year and kw, and if there are no entries in the joined table, it returns the values from the table account, and all other values as `NULL`.

But it doesnt return usernames, in case there are entries in the table "zeitplanung" which doesn't meet the cafeterias (kw, year).

How do I have to write that query to:

- get all entries from second table in case matching entries exist
- get the username and second table entries as NULL in case the WHERE statement won't fit.

Comment: I'm using a default MySQL Server, but as far as i know such default  querys should run on bouth

Comment: sample data and expected result would be useful for a meaningful answer,

Comment: http://i.epvpimg.com/6Qnfbab.png thats a screen of the table.
in case for example kw = 40 in the upper query i would expect:
http://i.epvpimg.com/0BmQdab.png and in case of kw = 41 i would except bouth id|s, usernames, cnames, but rest of the data as NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are filtering out the `NULL` results in your `WHERE` clause.  To keep them, move any filtering conditions for the `OUTER` tables to their `ON` clause:

```
SELECT account.id as id, `cname`, `username`, `state`, `dow` 
FROM account 
LEFT JOIN zeitplanung 
ON account.id = zeitplanung.user_id 
AND zeitplanung.kw = 43
AND zeitplanung.year = 2017
WHERE account.hide = 0;
```

Comment: Wouldn't that imply an `inner join` if you don't filter for `NULL`?

Comment: @WEI_DBA No, if you move your conditions to the `ON` clause, the `LEFT JOIN` will return a `NULL` if they didn't match.  With the conditions in the `WHERE` clause, the `LEFT JOIN` would still return a `NULL`, but the `WHERE` clause will then filter those out (`WHERE` executes after the `JOIN`).

Comment: thank you very much, looks similar to my first query :D have to check the differents
ah the different is that you put the where to the join, havnt known this works :) thanks a lot

Comment: Duh... The way it was structured I didn't notice the Where was below the conditional `ON`. My bad.